# Какая переменная передает массив на сервер?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

на фенсибокс есть такой пример аякс запроса:

```
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        cache:false,
        url: "/data/login.php",
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
             $.fancybox(data);
        }
     });
```

так вот, как определить в какой переменной был передан массив серверу, как это в php вывести, а именно data: `$(this).serializeArray()`?

Answer (score 3):

Укажите явно

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    cache:false,
    url: "/data/login.php",
    data: {param: $(this).serializeArray()},
    success: function(data) {
        $.fancybox(data);
    }
});
```

В php принимаете переменную $_POST['param'].

P.S. Сразу не обратил внимание на одну вещь - до использования $.ajax(), лучше загнать весь массив в переменную (напр.,*var someArr = $(this).serializeArray()*), т.к. $(this) в самом ajax-е может быть не виден.

Comment: Я бы сказал - this не может быть виден, верно подмечено.

Comment: а в php как его вывести, допустим одну пару ключ-значение массива?

Comment: как-то так:

    if(!empty($_POST['param'])) {
        print_r(unserialize($_POST['param']));
    }

Comment: да, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, в данном примере - данные отправляются без заголовка формы. А это то именно то, чот заставляет PHP распарсить отправленные клиентом значения в глобальную переменную `$_POST`. Если `print_r($_POST);` выводит пустой массив - так оно и есть. К счастью - решить эту проблему довольно просто:

```
 $cleanPostData = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
 $post = unserialize( $cleanPostData );
 print_r( $post ); // и того массив данных
```

Либо, как уже написано выше - укажите параметр явно, но, в вашем случае, от сериализации вас это не спасет.